# How to set fabSize image on design library's FAB background?

Tags: android

How can I set an image(whose dimension are of normal fabSize) as design library's FAB background. So, that my image is visible as a whole FAB instead of an icon with background color.

Answer (score 0):

`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` extends `View`, so you could use the `android:background` property with your drawable :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:background:"@drawable/your_image/>
```

Does that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

To remove default content padding in design library's FAB button, we have to override setPadding(...) function as below:

```
public class MyFAB extends FloatingActionButton {
    public MyFAB(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyFAB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyFAB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    }
}
```

and then just use MyFAB instead of FloatingActionButton in xml.